# Python Tensorflow and OpenCV on Apple Silicon M1

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, apple-m1

I try to use OpenCV and Tensorflow with Python on Apple silicon M1.
I'm able to use Tensorflow, but install OpenCV in my environment fails

`pip3 install opencv-python`

Even build opencv-python by my own locally fails on numpy

```
git clone https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python.git
cd opencv-python
ENABLE_CONTRIB=0 
ENABLE_HEADLESS=1
pip wheel . --verbose
```

with

> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
> /Users/hannes/git/city-simulator/tensorflow_venv2/bin/python3
> /Users/hannes/git/city-simulator/tensorflow_venv2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix
> /private/var/folders/np/7ckckk8s5fd169kvnnfhjkk40000gr/T/pip-build-env-3zg4n104/overlay
> --no-warn-script-location -v --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel scikit-build cmake pip 'numpy==1.13.3; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_machine !=
> '"'"'aarch64'"'"'' 'numpy==1.19.3; python_version>='"'"'3.6'"'"' and
> sys_platform == '"'"'linux'"'"' and platform_machine ==
> '"'"'aarch64'"'"'' 'numpy==1.14.5; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and
> platform_machine != '"'"'aarch64'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3;
> python_version=='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_machine !=
> '"'"'aarch64'"'"'' 'numpy==1.19.3; python_version>='"'"'3.9'"'"' and
> platform_machine != '"'"'aarch64'"'"'' Check the logs for full command
> output.

Even build numpy by my own fails

```
git clone git@github.com:numpy/numpy.git
cd numpy
OPENBLAS="$(brew --prefix openblas)" MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=11.1 python3 -m pip install cython --no-use-pep517
OPENBLAS="$(brew --prefix openblas)" MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=11.1 python3 -m pip install numpy --no-use-pep517
OPENBLAS="$(brew --prefix openblas)" MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=11.1 python3 -m pip install pandas --no-use-pep517
OPENBLAS="$(brew --prefix openblas)" MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=11.1 python3 -m pip install pybind11 --no-use-pep517
OPENBLAS="$(brew --prefix openblas)" MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=11.1 python3 -m pip install scipy --no-use-pep517
brew install libjpeg zlib
python3 -m pip install pillow
python3 -m pip install matplotlib
OPENBLAS="$(brew --prefix openblas)" MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=11.1 python3 -m pip install scikit-learn --no-use-pep517
OPENBLAS="$(brew --prefix openblas)" MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=11.1 python3 -m pip install statsmodels --no-use-pep517
cd ../opencv-python
pip wheel . --verbose
pip install numpy --no-index --find-links file:///Users/hannes/git/city-simulator/numpy/numpy
```

all without errors, bun on last I see this

```
Looking in links: file:///Users/hannes/git/city-simulator/numpy/numpy
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /Users/hannes/git/city-simulator/tensorflow_venv2/lib/python3.8/site-packages (1.18.5)
```

and `pip wheel . --verbose` still runs into same error

Answer (score 3):

I made it work with conda !

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge/releases/download/4.9.2-7/Mambaforge-4.9.2-7-MacOSX-arm64.sh 
chmod +x Mambaforge-4.9.2-7-MacOSX-arm64.sh
./Mambaforge-4.9.2-7-MacOSX-arm64.sh
which python
file $(which python)
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mwidjaja1/DSOnMacARM/main/environment.yml
conda env create --file=/Users/hannes/Downloads/environment.yml --name=condaVenv
conda activate condaVenv
pip3 install --upgrade --force --no-dependencies \
  https://github.com/apple/tensorflow_macos/releases/download/v0.1alpha3/tensorflow_macos-0.1a3-cp38-cp38-macosx_11_0_$(uname -m).whl \
  https://github.com/apple/tensorflow_macos/releases/download/v0.1alpha3/tensorflow_addons_macos-0.1a3-cp38-cp38-macosx_11_0_$(uname -m).whl
python -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)' 
conda install opencv
python -c 'import tensorflow as tf; import cv2; print(cv2.__version__); print(tf.__version__)'
```

shows now

```
4.5.1
2.4.0-rc0
```

ATTENTION during copy&paste this command !

When you copy it, you will see

[image]

Please remove `\` after paste

Comment: Great answer! Just rework the pip3 install commands it shows
    zsh: parse error near `)' but this is fixed easily by looking at https://github.com/apple/tensorflow_macos/releases/tag/v0.1alpha3 where you can get name of the wheel you need.

Comment: This is a paste error from stackoverflow. I updated my solution @Pr0ph3t_sec